# Trouble with word-boundary (\b)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of keywords, and I want to know whether at least one of the keywords is found within some string that has been submitted. I further want to be absolutely sure that it is the keyword that has been matched, and not something that is very similar to the word.

Say, for example, that our keywords are `[English, Eng, En]` because we are looking for some variation of English.

Now, say that the input from a user is `i h8 eng class`, or something equally provocative and illiterate - then the `eng` should be matched. It should also fail to match a word like `england` or some odd thing `chen`, even though it's got the `en` bit.

So, in my infinite lack of wisdom I believed I could do something along the lines of this in order to match one of my array items with the input:

```
.match(RegExp('\b('+array.join('|')+')\b','i'))
```

With the thinking that the regular expression would look for matches from the array, now presented like `(English|Eng|En)` and then look to see whether there were zero-width word bounds on either side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **double** the backslashes.

When you create a regex with the `RegExp()` constructor, you're passing in a string. JavaScript string constant syntax **also** treats the backslash as a meta-character, for quoting quotes etc.  Thus, the backslashes will be effectively stripped out **before** the `RegExp()` code even runs!

By doubling them, the step of parsing the string will leave one backslash behind. Then the `RegExp()` parser will see the single backslash before the "b" and do the right thing.

Comment: That seems to make everything better! Like a plaster when you're little. Much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to double the backslashes in a JavaScript string or you'll encode a *Backspace* character:

```
.match(RegExp('\\b('+array.join('|')+')\\b','i'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double-escape a `\b`, cause it have special value in strings:

```
.match(RegExp('\\b('+array.join('|')+')\\b','i'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is an escape sequence inside string literals (see table 2.1 on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals)). You should escape it by adding one extra slash:

```
.match(RegExp('\\b('+array.join('|')+')\\b','i'))
```

You do not need to escape `\b` when used inside a regular expression literal:

```
/\b(english|eng|en)\b/i
```